# chrome doesn't respect image aspect ratio in flexbox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, flexbox

Flexboxes make it easy to make layouts that grow and shrink intelligently based on available space.  I was using this feature to draw two images that each take up half of the width of the screen.  In Firefox, the images render as expected and maintain their aspect ratio but in Chrome the images are horizontally squashed to 50% each and left at their full height vertically.

Here's a demo of what I'm talking about:

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <img src="http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows/main/2b03b0c4-85f7-4c28-9c60-1c7af2a62fa8_5.jpg" />
  <img src="http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows/main/b89eff70-398d-4b1b-8806-02458a185c5a_5.jpg" />
</div>
```

I've read in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081412/css-flexbox-images-not-preserving-aspect-ratio) that this is a Chrome bug.  How can I cleanly work around it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use display:flex? If you use display:inline-block, you get what you're looking for.

Comment: @Cruiser I'd rather use flexbox but you're right, `display: inline-block` does the trick just fine.  (As long as I remember to comment out the whitespace between the divs)

Comment: Where have you read that this is a Chrome bug? I couldn't find that statement on the linked page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The items in a flexbox will stretch their size by default.
Seeing you want them to not stretch on the cross-axis (vertical), you can use the `align-items` on the container, to change the default behaviour.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/g1vLff23/

**CSS**

```
.flexbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because @chelsea's solution leaves lots of extraneous whitespace where the images used to be.

Comment: Was looking all over for this answer. Thank you!

Comment: The `align-items` part was actually sufficient for me to add. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Apply `object-fit: scale-down;` to the images. Yes, adding `height: auto;` does not do the trick, unfortunately. Similar issue solved here: [max-width of img inside flexbox doesn't preserve aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853749/max-width-of-img-inside-flexbox-doesnt-preserve-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Brilliant! I was banging my head against the table for some days trying to make it work!

Comment: If you need this to work on Internet Explorer, this solution doesn’t work, unfortunately…

Comment: This solved an issue only on chrome for me where aspect ratio was fine on load but using js to add/remove `display: none` to show hide image wouldn't preserve aspect ratio

Answer (score -2):

You can solve this by adding the `height` property to your `img` rule and giving it a value of `auto`:

```
img{
    height:auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  Would you mind updating your answer with a sample?